# Creating listeners with SQL Server AlwaysOn suddenly stopped working

Tags: sql-server-2012, active-directory, alwayson

Problem: I created 10 AlwaysOn Availability Groups with SQL Server without a problem.  Suddenly, it stopped worked and I kept getting this ONLY on the "create the listener" part:

Msg 19471, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
The WSFC cluster could not bring the Network Name resource with DNS name 'L_MyListener' online. The DNS name may have been taken or have a conflict with existing name services, or the WSFC cluster service may not be running or may be inaccessible. Use a different DNS name to resolve name conflicts, or check the WSFC cluster log for more information.

Sometimes I also got Msg 19476.   This was all maddening because one moment I was creating listeners and availability groups, feeling like a guru, and then everything stopped and I lost hours of time.

So how do you solve this?  Of course, Microsoft's own suggested text in the above error description was NOT helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, each listener is really creating a mini "computer" in Active Directory if you look. And... here's the kicker, a domain user can only join a computer to a domain a limited number of times and that default is 10.  Who would have thought that adding listeners equates with joining users to a domain!???!  Microsoft really should have made this listener thing more intuitive, at least in their description text of possible problems.

Well, on your Domain Controller, open ADSI Edit, configure it the first time to look at your default naming context of your domain, like "DC=yourname..." with the CN= rows below that.  Now, right click on the "DC=" line, choose Properties and navigate down to ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota and increase the limit from 10 to something else like 100.

You may need to run "GPUPDATE /FORCE" on the SQL Servers where you want to try again to add the listener.  You may also have to clean up the mess it left (i.e. delete and restore the bad attempt at setting up your group and listener) before you try again.

With SQL Server 2016 supposedly going to require each database be in its own group, with its own listener, people will hit this limit of 10 quite easily!

I hope this helps you.  If so, please mark this as the answer on the left.  Of course, there are other reasons why people may get this error, as in the Microsoft error now but this whole post is for people who had it working just fine and then suddenly it stopped.